# Git SVN was working, rebase now hangs

Tags: git, git-svn

I just did a `git svn rebase` no problem on Friday afternoon.

Monday morning, it's hanging and resulting in an error like "WFSO timed out"

```
$ git svn rebase
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

How do I get it back to working again? 
Last time it got into this state, I did a `git svn fetch` all over again, which worked, but rebuild the local repo from scratch and so was very time consuming.  Hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Can you paste the actual commands and errors?

Comment: I am getting similar problem. Following is the console output: Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
Counting objects: 2664517, done.
C:\Git\bin\perl.exe: *** WFSO timed out
Writing objects:  20% (543738/2664517)

Comment: I'm doing `git svn rebase -l`.  No output for me.  It just hangs.  Task Manager shows that new Git and Perl processes are spawned every couple seconds, but they die about as fast, so I average a total of three Git processes and three Perl processes at any given time.

Comment: Has anyone solved in any way? I'm getting the same situation

Comment: "git svn rebase" hangs, same here for me

Answer (score 0):

Try aborting the rebase

`git rebase --abort`

If that gives an error (likely) follow instructions to reset head, after that try aborting again:

`git update-ref refs/heads/master COMMIT_IN_MESSAGE`

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
git svn fetch
git rebase
```

And it seems working.